# PHP7.2 ZTS + PThreads on Ubuntu 16.04; Install additional packages

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have a test server running Ubuntu 16.04. I managed to compile PHP 7.2.2 with ZTS from source and installed PThreads on it.

Now, how do I proceed with further setting up PHP without damaging my installation? If I try to install, let's say PHP Curl or Apache's PHP 7.2 module, Ubuntu wants me to install php7.2-common, etc. which would overwrite my current installation.

Is there a safe way to install additional PHP modules and hook up PHP with Apache2?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you compile your own version of php, you can't use the extension packages from in the apt repos.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Good to know. What would be the best practice to have a self-compiled version of PHP be recognized by Apache2?

Comment: There's mod_php, mod_fcgid or mod_proxy_fcgi for fastcgi processes, and mod_suphp.  It's up to you how you want to set it up for Apache, each has different features. You'll have to set it up yourself though.  I'd recommend mod_php or mod_proxy_fcgi.

Comment: Thank you very much, Devon!